# Why would string case comparison suddenly stop working in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, string, tolower

Does anyone know how is the following possible? All of a sudden string comparison using `.ToLower` and `Lcase` stopped working.

If I do this in the immediate window:

```
?lcase(text)
"menu"
?lcase(text)="menu"
False
```

This just started a few minutes ago. I'm using:

- .NET 4.5.2
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- Visual Basic

EDIT:
The source of this problem is from here:[Please how can i return decoded bytes instead of text from a CryptoStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435607/please-how-can-i-return-decoded-bytes-instead-of-text-from-a-cryptostream)

After making that code change.

Comment: What is your current `Culture` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel unchanged, default culture

Comment: lcase? legacy system?

Comment: LCase - Lower case vb.net

Comment: ahh... i have binary compare on... should that matter?

Comment: the text being compared is got from UTF8.GetString(data) ... should this matter?

Comment: @CharlesO What is that default culture? What you have set in your regional settings in control panel?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel EN English(United States)

Comment: A .net string is UTF-16, if you are binary comparing a UTF8 then there is the change of having differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would stop using `LCase` because it is VB 6 compability code.

Second I would not use .NETs build in `"string".ToLower()` or `"string".ToUpper()` in string comparisons because that can lead to some unexpected results for some locals.

Better use `text.Equals("menu", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

I don't know what the root cause of your problem is, but hope that helps.

Comment: the text being compared is got from UTF8.GetString(data) ...  ill change all my string comparison to what you suggestion..tedious, but will take away the guessing game. Thanks.

Comment: nope, no luck
?text.Equals("menu", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
False

Comment: text could contain unprintable chars, just a wild guess what is the output from `UTF8.GetBytes(text).Last().Equals(New Byte(0))`, if true, your string  is NULL terminated which ist not common for .NET.

Comment: ?UTF8.GetBytes(text).Last().Equals(New Byte())

True

Comment: ?UTF8.GetBytes(text)
{Length=16}
    (0): 77
    (1): 101
    (2): 110
    (3): 117
    (4): 0
    (5): 0
    (6): 0
    (7): 0
    (8): 0
    (9): 0
    (10): 0
    (11): 0
    (12): 0
    (13): 0
    (14): 0
    (15): 0

Comment: ahh... the text is the result of a decryption. it seems the decypted bytes leaves empty bytes  in the decryption buffer

Comment: Try `text.TrimEnd(Convert.ToChar(0))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It led me to the root of the problem.
 I had to remove the empty bytes left over from decrypting with CryptoStream

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
'Declaration
Public Shared Function Compare ( _
    strA As String, _
    strB As String, _
    ignoreCase As Boolean _
) As Integer
```

Result Less than zero = strA is less than strB.
Result Zero = strA equals strB.
Result Greater than zero = strA is greater than strB.